# Question about persistent communication requests in MPI

Tags: mpi

I have come across the following passage from the document "MPI: A Message-Passing Interface Standard Version 4.0":

> A *persistent communication request* is deallocated by a call to `MPI_REQUEST_FREE`. The call to `MPI_REQUEST_FREE` can occur at any point in the program
> after the persistent request was created. However, the request will be deallocated only after it becomes *inactive*. *Active* receive requests should not be *freed* . Otherwise, it will not be possible to check that the receive has *completed*.

I'm trying to understand how both these sentences can be correct:

1. "the request will be deallocated only after it becomes *inactive*"
2. "*Active* receive requests should not be *freed*"

The first sentence seems to imply that **only** **inactive** requests **can** be freed. But the second one appears to be saying that **active** (receive) requests **can** be freed but **should not** be freed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `MPI_Request_free` on an active request, your handle becomes null. But as point 2 notes, that is not a good idea because you can no longer check on the status of the communication.

However, by free'ing you only lose the handle: in case of a still-ongoing communication the actual request object still exists, taking up memory. That one will only be deallocated -- meaning, by MPI, not by you -- when the communication is finished.

Put it another way, `MPI_Request_free` indeed de-allocates the request object, but only immediately if it corresponds to an inactive request. Otherwise the deallocation happens when the request becomes inactive.